# How to make forms in ModalDialog (IsDlg) respect Source and redirect accordingly to a 'thanks' page after submit?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, forms-services, redirect, query-string

Has someone already solved the conflict between `IsDlg` and `Source` query string parameters to allow a redirect after form submission in a `SP.UI.ModalDialog`? Per chance even when an InfoPath form is involved?

Answer (score 3):

You would have to overwrite the Save Action using `PreSaveAction()` in order to look at the `Source`, because how I understand it, `Source` is ignored if `IsDlg` is present.

Comment: I don't make this as the final answer because I'd like to address the InfoPath aspect as well.

Comment: You could change the InfoPath view to a thanks view and have a rule to change the view?